# Twig Tweak 3 and drupal_field in node twig template

Tags: nodes, 9

I have a Drupal 8 site with Twig Tweak 2 which I've upgraded to Drupal 9 with Twig Tweak 3. This has broken a custom node twig template.

With Twig Tweak 2, this worked:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_library_photo', 'node' }}
```

I gather from reading the documentation, this should work with Twig Tweak 3:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_library_photo', 'node', node.id) }}
```

But it doesn't. As a proof of concept, I hardcoded the node id of one of the library pages:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_library_photo', 'node', 117) }}
```

Also doesn't work. (And when I say it doesn't work, there's nothing rendered in the HTML output and no errors are thrown.)

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `field_library_photo` configured in your "default" view mode for your node? Display settings are the fourth arg (which you're not using) and the default value is to use the settings for the field on the "default" view mode.

Comment: Aha! That unearthed a mess I'd made while trying different ways of setting up this unique content. I did have "default" set the correct way but I had all the fields hidden in "full content". Under Custom Display Settings, I had turned on "full content". I turned off "full content" and voila! Thank you. I don't think I would have ever stumbled on that on my own.